# Load csv from newman using nodejs

Tags: node.js, postman, newman

I have the following code that is working now.

I have a script with javascript that use nodejs and read a csv file but I don't know how to use the data from csv in newman.run

```
var fs = require('fs');
var people = [];
var fileContents = fs.readFileSync('users.csv');
var lines = fileContents.toString().split('\n');
const newman = require('newman'); // require newman in your project
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    people.push(lines[i].toString().split(','));
}
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

    console.log(people[i][0]);

    newman.run({
        collection: require('collection.json'),
        environment: require('environment.json'),   
        reporters: 'htmlextra',     
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) { throw err; }
        console.log("i"+'collection run complete!');
    });

}
```

I try to explain what's happening.

I iterate over csv file correctly but I don't know how to pass the values of csv in body about post.

Could aynone help to me?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

To use a `datafile` with Newman, from a script - you would only need to add the `iterationData` key to the `newman.run` object and then reference the filename as the value.

```
const newman = require('newman');

newman.run({
    collection: require('collection.json'),
    environment: require('environment.json'),
    iterationData: '<path to file>/users.csv',   
    reporters: 'htmlextra',     
}, function (err) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
    console.log('collection run complete!');
});
```

To use the values in the requests, you would need to add this variable names using the `{{var_name}}` syntax which would reference the CSV column headings.

More information about working with data files can be found here:

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection-runs/working-with-data-files/